# How to the get the beginning of day of a date in javascript -- factoring in timezone

Tags: javascript, mongodb, timezone

I am struggling to find out the beginning of day factoring in timezones in javascript.  Consider the following:

```
   var raw_time = new Date(this.created_at);
   var offset_time = new Date(raw_hour.getTime() + time_zone_offset_in_ms);

   // This resets timezone to server timezone
   var offset_day = new Date(offset_time.setHours(0,0,0,0))
   // always returns 2011-12-08 05:00:00 UTC, no matter what the offset was!

   // This has the same issue:
   var another_approach_offset_day = new Date(offset_time.getFullYear(),offset_time.getMonth(),offset_time.getHours())
```

I expect when i pass a Pacific Timezone offset, to get: `2011-12-08 08:00:00 UTC` and so on.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

I think that part of the issue is that [setHours](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp) method sets the hour (from 0 to 23), according to local time.

Also note that I am using javascript embedded in mongo, so I am unable to use any additional libraries.

Thanks!

---

Jeez, so this was really hard for me, but here is the final solution that I came up with the following solution.  The trick was I need to use setHours or SetUTCHours to get the beginning of a day -- the only choices I have are system time and UTC.  So I get the beginning of a UTC day, then add back the offset!

```
// Goal is given a time and a timezone, find the beginning of day
function(timestamp,selected_timezone_offset) {
  var raw_time = new Date(timestamp)
  var offset_time = new Date(raw_time.getTime() + selected_timezone_offset);
  offset_time.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
  var beginning_of_day = new Date(offset_time.getTime() - selected_timezone_offset);
  return beginning_of_day;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript **all** dates are *stored* as UTC.  That is, the serial number returned by `date.valueOf()` is the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  But, when you examine a date via `.toString()` or `.getHours()`, etc., you get the value in local time.  That is, the local time of the system running the script.  You can get the value in UTC with methods like `.toUTCString()` or `.getUTCHours()`, etc.

So, you *can't* get a date in an arbitrary timezone, it's all UTC (or local).  But, of course, you can get a string representation of a date in whatever timezone you like if you know the UTC offset.  The easiest way would be to subtract the UTC offset from the date and call `.getUTCHours()` or `.toUTCString()` or whatever you need:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - 480); // get pacific standard time
d.toUTCString(); // returns "Fri, 9 Dec 2011 12:56:53 UTC"
```

Of course, you'll need to ignore that "UTC" at the end if you use `.toUTCString()`.  You could just go:

```
d.toUTCString().replace(/UTC$/, "PST");
```

**Edit:** Don't worry about when timezones overlap date boundaries.  If you pass `setHours()` a negative number, it will subtract those hours from midnight yesterday.  Eg:

```
var d = new Date(2011, 11, 10, 15); // d represents Dec 10, 2011 at 3pm local time
d.setHours(-1);                     // d represents Dec 9, 2011 at 11pm local time
d.setHours(-24);                    // d represents Dec 8, 2011 at 12am local time
d.setHours(52);                     // d represents Dec 10, 2011 at 4am local time
```

Comment: Gilly3 -- thanks,  I feel that this gets me close.  I am struggling how to get the beginning of day to work with timezones.  Man -- I hate timezones. ;)

Comment: I guess the issue is that [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp](setHours) method sets the hour (from 0 to 23), according to **local time**.  How do we work around that?

Comment: @Jonathan - There is [`setHours()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a5xhxy(VS.94).aspx) for local time and [`setUTCHours()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwybddk2(VS.94).aspx) for UTC time.  If you are trying to increment the hour, it doesn't matter if you use `d.setHours(d.getHours() + 1)` or `d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() + 1)`, as long as you either use the local version for both get and set or the UTC version for both get and set.  But, if you are setting a specific hour of the day in UTC, use `setUTCHours()`.

Comment: @Jonathan - Also, while `getHours()` returns 0-23, `setHours()` accepts *any* integer, positive or negative.  If your date `d` contains `2011/12/10 15:00:00` and you call `d.setHours(-1)`, `d` will now contain `2011/12/09 23:00:00`.  If you call `d.setHours(-24*365)`, `d` will contain `2010/12/10 00:00:00` - 1 year earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Where does the time_zone_offset_in_ms variable you use come from?  Perhaps it is unreliable, and you should be using Date's getTimezoneOffset() method.  There is an example at the following URL:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getTimezoneOffset.asp

Comment: thanks, my time_zone_offset_in_ms is passed in via my Rails application, i have confirmed it to be correct.  In needs to be passed in the was, for my users choose which timezone they want to see their data.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the date from a different date string you can do the following:

```
var currentDate = new Date(this.$picker.data('date'));
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, -currentDate.getTimezoneOffset(), 0, 0);
```

(based on the codebase for a project I did)

Answer (score 0):

```
var aDate = new Date();
var startOfTheDay = new Date(aDate.getTime() - aDate.getTime() % 86400000)
```

Will create the beginning of the day, of the day in question

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat). This is also how [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/zones.html) handles timezones.

The code below can convert any date with any timezone to its beginging/end of the time.

```js
const beginingOfDay = (options = {}) => {
  const { date = new Date(), timeZone } = options;
  const parts = Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
    timeZone,
    hourCycle: "h23",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    second: "numeric",
  }).formatToParts(date);
  const hour = parseInt(parts.find((i) => i.type === "hour").value);
  const minute = parseInt(parts.find((i) => i.type === "minute").value);
  const second = parseInt(parts.find((i) => i.type === "second").value);
  return new Date(
    1000 *
      Math.floor(
        (date - hour * 3600000 - minute * 60000 - second * 1000) / 1000
      )
  );
};

const endOfDay = (...args) =>
  new Date(beginingOfDay(...args).getTime() + 86399999);

const beginingOfYear = () => {};

console.log(beginingOfDay({ timeZone: "GMT" }));
console.log(endOfDay({ timeZone: "GMT" }));
console.log(beginingOfDay({ timeZone: "Asia/Tokyo" }));
console.log(endOfDay({ timeZone: "Asia/Tokyo" }));
```